# Magento 1.9.4 - Backup function in admin went missing after upgrade

Tags: magento, upgrade, magento-1.9

After successful upgrade to Magento 1.9.4 - the system backup function in completely gone in backend admin. Beats me?

Thanks,

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: You're right, please close!